# A place for telekinesis in physics?

Tags: physics, teleportation

I am a writer, and I have attempting my first fiction novel. However, I like to have things figured out in a way that works with the laws of physics in the universe, at least to a certain regard. For example, telekinesis will play a role in my stories, with a particular character having the ability. Could someone give me a few options of how the physics side of things could be explained?

If he were like Magneto, and could just control metal, I could easily explain it the way Marvel has, with him being able to control magnetic fields. However, what about regular telekinesis? I could probably say that he affects gravity. But, are there any other ideas you all might have? Maybe something to do with matter, dark matter even, or something completely off the wall?

Right now, all I have is that he is able to generate energy from his body that flows invisibly to whatever it is going to influence.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/75956/limits-of-telekinesis
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/93534/telekinesis-in-science-fiction
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/141012/how-could-my-hard-telekinesis-work
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/148561/how-can-powerful-telekinesis-avoid-violating-newtons-3rd-law
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/111442/how-to-operate-telekinesis-and-a-kinetic-shield-using-science-based-magic     Lots of prior art here.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding, Allex. Your question is likely to be closed because it is a duplicate of earlier questions. If you believe that you have a unique aspect that isn't covered by the earlier questions, feel free to ask it specifically.

Comment: I’ll probably be reading a few of those links myself. Telekinesis is a very vague word, it would be nice to read a sensible investigation.